# angular select default to first option

Tags: angularjs, select

I cannot seem to get my dropdown to default to having the first store selected.

html:

```
<select 
      id="store" 
      class="form-control input-inline input-medium"
      ng-model="orderVm.Stores.selectedStore.id">
    <option 
         ng-repeat="store in orderVm.Stores" 
         value="{{store.Id}}">
        {{store.MarketplaceName}}
    </option>
</select>
{{orderVm.Stores.selectedStore}}
```

vm.Stores (loaded from a local JSON file):

```
[
  {
    "Id": 1,
    "MarketplaceId": 1,
    "MarketplaceName": "Etsy"
    ]
  },
  {
    "Id": 2,
    "MarketplaceId": 2,
    "MarketplaceName": "Shopify"
  }
]
```

controller:

```
angular
    .module('WizmoApp')
    .controller('orderController', orderController);

orderController.$inject = ['$http', '$location', 'toastr', 'DTColumnDefBuilder', 'DTOptionsBuilder', 'Cart', 'OrderService', 'PackageService'];

function orderController($http, $location, toastr, DTColumnDefBuilder, DTOptionsBuilder, Cart, OrderService, PackageService) {
        var vm = this;
        vm.Stores = json; //from file 
        vm.Stores.selectedStore = {
            id: vm.Stores[0].Id, 
            name: vm.Stores[0].MarketplaceName 
        };

        OrderService.getOrdersGroupedByStore(function (json) {
            vm.Stores = json;
            vm.selectedStore = {};
        });
```

routes.js:

```
            .state('layout.orders', {
                url: '/orders',
                templateUrl: '/Content/js/apps/store/views/order.html',
                controller: 'orderController',
                controllerAs: 'orderVm',
                data: { pageTitle: 'Orders' }
            })
```

(It doesn't help that the first option is blank, but first things first.)

I'd use ng-options but frankly, it's even more obscure than this.

Comment: I don;t see how it doesn't match. The controller is called orderVm. So orderVm.Stores in view is vm.Stores in controller. I'll keep looking at it.

Answer (score 4):

https://jsbin.com/kanaco/edit?html,js,output

I write a sample code for you.
Use `ng-options` for select.

edit:

```
<select id="store" class="form-control input-inline input-medium" 
    ng-model="ctrl.selectedStores" 
    ng-options="item.MarketplaceName for item in ctrl.Stores"
    ng-init="ctrl.selectedStores=ctrl.Stores[0]">
</select>
```

You can use `ng-options` for repeat option, and use `ng-init` for default select.

Comment: Please include code in your answer rather than linking to an outside source.

Comment: I get it! Thanks for comment. This's my first post.

Comment: It looks like using ng-init in this way is discouraged in Angular: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit.

Answer (score 3):

Never use `ng-repeat` to build select options.  Instead, use `ng-options`, which has a dedicated directive for this:

```
<select 
  id="store" 
  class="form-control input-inline input-medium"
  ng-model="orderVm.Stores.selectedStore"
  ng-options="store.ID as store.MarketplaceName for store in orderVm.Stores">
</select>
```

In your controller, you need to assign a default value to the select model:

```
orderVm.Stores.selectedStore = 1;
```

This would cause the Etsy option to be selected when the controller loads.  Note that the model is just an id here, you don't need to use an object.  The reason you were getting an empty option is that Angular could not bind the model to any of the options.

I had a [very similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37476289/angularjs-ng-model-in-select-binding-to-name-instead-of-value) to yours and was asissted by a kind guru.

Comment: I tried ng-options first but I just can't make heads or tails of it. Your suggestion did not work as-is and I don't really know what it's supposed to be doing so I'm at a loss to debug it.. Why do you say store.ID as store.MarketplaceName? That's a string - only for display.

Comment: Follow the link I gave.  You didn't post your full Angular code so I can only guess at this point.  I had big problems with `ng-repeat`.

Comment: Ah, It seems to be an asynch problem. Your code did not work until I moved the JSON into the controller.So I've got to initialize the select after the JSON is loaded.

Comment: All your code should be in the controller, and I don't know why you are referring to it as `orderVm.Stores`.  There should be a scoped JSON variable called `$scope.Stores` which contains the name/value pairs you want to appear in the select.

Comment: Using the recommended pattern  var vm = this; and controller as orderVm.

Comment: Still need to figure out how to refresh the select once the data is loaded.

Comment: You don't need to refresh the select, the Angular framework will handle this for you.

Comment: I have updated the opening post to include the controller header and the route. The select is initlializing before the data is available. It has an empty option at the top of the list which goes away as soon as I select any option. But it won;t default to Etsy.

Comment: Inspector shows first option as <option value="?" selected="selected"></option>. Goes away as soon as I choose a valid option.

Comment: As I mentioned in my answer, the reason this is happening is because Angular cannot bind the default value of the model to an actual option in your select.  Your code has many problems.